# how to save ForeignKey object and its parent object at the same time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-one

Angular 8, Django 3. I have two models `Recipe` and `Ingredients`. I am using `ngModels` on the frontend to send data to Django to create a `Recipe` model. On one page when you click "submit", all the `Recipe` and `Ingredients` data is sent to the backend.

From what i read about `ManyToOne` relationships the `models.ForeignKey` should go on the model that is part of the "many". So there are "many" `Ingredients` per `Recipe`, so i have the `Foreignkey` on `Ingredients`.

My problem is when I send all this data to Django my `Ingredients` are not being created because there is no `ingredients` field on the `RecipeSerializer`.

**models.py**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Ingredients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class AddRecipe(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeFullSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ['name']

class RecipeFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'ingredients']
```

**sample data**

```
ingredients: Array(1)
0: {name: "23"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
name: "23"
```

I am getting an array of `Ingredients` data on the backend just not sure how to save it all with a Foreignkey to `Recipes` at the same time. I guess I could create a custom view that does all this for me but I thought there would be a class based view that could do this.

**error**

```
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `users.serializers.RecipeFullSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

Comment: please do rewrite your *sample data* in JSON format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the ingredients as [read_only](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only), so it won't create them. You need to remove that if you want to save them.

Update: Also, you need to override the create method. Check [Writing .create() methods for nested representations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) in the docs.

It would be something like this:

```
class RecipeFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'ingredients']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            Ingredient.objects.create(recipe=recipe, **ingredient)

        return recipe
```

Comment: wow that was an excellent catch, but now i am gettting a `Bad Request Error`..

Comment: Add a request example to see how you are sending the data to the backend

Comment: i edited with a request example, hope thats what you are looking for?

Comment: edited again for new error, which looks like it answers my question that you cannot use a class based view for nested serialization, so i have to write my own correct?

Comment: That sample data is not well formatted so it's not very useful. But yeah, that error is telling you that you need to override the default `create` method for the serializer

Comment: thanks so much for you help, if you wanna add that to your answer i will accept

Comment: Added an update, maybe it's not 100% working but it should be something like that. That way you create the recipe and all the ingredients related